# C# read boolean from database

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable, boolean

I am trying to read a boolean (`enabled` field) from the database, and use it to initialize objects. I am using a data table:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);

List<Account> accounts = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
    new Account
    {
        name = row.Field<string>("user")
        enabled = row.Field<Boolean>("enabled")
    }).ToList();
```

The field `enabled` is declared as a `boolean` in the mysql database.
In the database the `enabled` field is defined as: `enabled boolean default false,`

I get an error when trying to read the `enabled` variable:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll but was not handled in user code

I get the error at the `enabled = row.Field<Boolean>("enabled")` line. 
I think the error is the boolean data type of C#.
I got the same problem also when I use `enabled = "1".Equals(row.Field("enabled"))` and `enabled = row.Field("enabled")==1`. If I replace it with `enabled = true` everything works.

UPDATE:
The database connection:

```
string connString = "SERVER=localhost" + ";" +
                "DATABASE=accs;" +
                "UID=root;" +
                "PASSWORD=root;";
MySqlConnection cnMySQL = new MySqlConnection(connString);
```

UPDATE2: a more detailed error message

> System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2147467262   Message=Specified cast is not valid.
>   Source=System.Data.DataSetExtensions   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.NullableField[TElem](Object
>   value)
>          at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[T](DataRow row, String columnName)
>          at WebApplication5.WebService1.<>c.b__1_0(DataRow
>   row) in WebService1.asmx.cs:line 88
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>          at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>          at WebApplication5.WebService1.getUserSentPackages(String userName) in WebService1.asmx.cs:line 87   InnerException

Comment: What is the SQL datatype of the enabled column?  Is it nullable?

Comment: `\`enabled\` boolean default false,` , but all rows from the table have the `enabled` field initialized.

Comment: Try `Boolean?`. And your `enabled` property of `Account` class must be `Boolean?` too.

Comment: where to try `Boolean`? In the database or in C#?

Comment: MySQL doesnt actually have a bool type and treats "bool" as an alias for `TINYINT`.  The real problem comes from NET not knowing that.  Add `;treattinyasboolean=True` to your connection string to  convert them

Comment: I should note that a DataTable is every bit as usable as a List<T> - there usually isnt a need to copy the data from one to another

Comment: @Plutonx I get an error if I add that in the connection string`An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code`

Comment: `string connString = "SERVER=localhost" + ";" +
                "DATABASE=accs;" +
                "UID=root;" +
                "PASSWORD=root;treattinyasboolean=True;";`

Comment: @JohnyL `Boolean?` didn't work

Comment: @Plutonx the code continues with `MySqlConnection cnMySQL = new MySqlConnection(connString);` ... i think that is the connection string.

Comment: Thats a grody way to build a connection string - try the ConnectionStringBuilder setting the `tiny...` flag (you can then copy the result to code)...Among other things exposing the root account in your app is a bad idea too.   `"allowuservariables=False;treattinyasboolean=True;connectiontimeout=15;server=127.0.0.1;database=xxx;user id=yyy;password=zzz;port=3306"`  works perfectly.   https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: I got an error for the string: `{"Keyword not supported.\r\nParameter name: allowuservariables"}`. Do you use `MySqlConnection` class like I do?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html  the connstring posted was created by `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder`, so yeah, its valid.  You have something else going on, but you could remove `allowuservariables`

Comment: what connector-net version do you use?

Comment: This has officially become a chameleon question.  The error posted has nothing to do with the connection string or connecting but has to do with the loop.  It now looks like some rows have a null, so maybe fix the data or make `enabled` nullable (there *really* is no reason to fill a datatable just to take it back out to create a list!)

Comment: I made `enabled` not nullable, and I need lists because I create a webservice and I need to send objects in a XML format.

Comment: If you have a mix of `NULL` and non-`null` values in the column, you will trigger https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78917; values after the first `NULL` will be returned as `sbyte`, not `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments the Boolean type in MySql is a synonym for TinyInt(1). If you are unable to change the connection string as suggested the equivalent type in C# is `byte`. If there could be null values in the database then you should use `byte?` (nullable byte). The code would be:

```
enabled = row.Field<byte?>("enabled")==1
```

Comment: Yes: `An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
`

Comment: we have no idea where that is ocurring

Comment: Is this with your original connection string or the new one suggested above? This should work with the original connection string. I suggest you debug and look to see what the values are in the data table before you try to put it into the list.

Comment: How can I check those values? Can I also get the type automatically?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in your code you can then step through it. Hover over the datatable when it has been populated and you will be able to view the values. Also, unless you are using it for something else you could just populate your list directly from the data reader, the datatable may not be necessary.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by:

```
enabled = "1".Equals(row.Field<Object>("enabled").ToString())
```

If you want to check for false, you use `"false"` instead of `"1"`:

```
enabled = "false".Equals(row.Field<Object>("enabled").ToString())
```

Using `String` instead of `Object` doesn't work!

Comment: This will work, but it is poor form.

Converting (instantiating) to string, then comparing that with another string, feels obvious, but it's a fair amount of overhead.
In addition, the comparison doesn't read obviously/nicely at all.