# How to cast a tinyint value from a MySql column to C# using Linq?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, tinyint

I'm trying to run the below query using Linq:

```
var ResultRows = from MyRow in MyDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                         where Convert.ToBoolean(MyRow.Field<byte>("IsTrue")) == true
                         select MyRow;
```

where one of the column is a boolean (not null). I know that boolean in MySql is recorded as *tinyint* and is recognized as a *byte* in C#. I've tried converting to *int* but I keep getting the "specific cast is not valid" error. The only time it worked was when I changed the MySql's column datatype to *int* and compare against that. How can I get this to work without changing the Mysql's column datatype?

Comment: check if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/48131615/14973743

Comment: "I know that boolean in MySql is recorded as tinyint and is recognized as a byte in C#." That's not necessarily true. Most .NET MySQL libraries will map a `TINYINT(1)` column as `bool`. Are you sure it's being returned as a `byte`?

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct.